# Wrong tikz arrow centering on cross-referencing node labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

The following code results in the arrow not beginning at the `\ell` but in the center of the colored box instead. How to fix that? (`remember picture` has been defined in the preamble to be included in every tikz environment)

```
\[
x(t) =
\int_0^t
\tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (t3) {$
\tikz[baseline]{\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (ell) {$\ell$}}
(z)$} }
\, ds
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[black,thick,->] (ell) to [in=90,out=245] +(225:2cm) node[anchor=north,text=black] {instant};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which reproduce your problem. So far is unclear, where should be arrow ... probably start at `\ell`, but where it should end?

Comment: Do not nest nodes. Also, to reference a node, you need to add the option `remember picture` to the relevant `tikz` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess/suspect, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

but I'm not sure. For above result you need to compile MWE below at least three times.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark} % <---
\tikzset{is/.style = {inner ysep=2pt}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\[
x(t) = \int_0^t \colorbox{blue!20}{$\tikzmarknode[is]{A}{\ell}(z)$}\, ds
\]
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[thick,->] (A.south) to [in=90,out=245] +(225:12mm) node[anchor=north] {instant};
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip
    \end{center}
\lipsum[1][3-5]
\end{document}
```

**Note:** Please in future consider my comment and in question always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example)!

**Addendum:**
for fun and show, how can you working simple solution convert to complex and error prone one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit, 
                shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style = {remember picture,baseline},
          MN/.style = {rectangle split,  rectangle split horizontal,
                       rectangle split parts=2,
                       inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=1pt, anchor=base},
         FIT/.style = {fit=#1, fill=cyan!50, inner sep=3pt, 
                       node contents={}},
         arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, semithick}   
         }

\begin{document}                    
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\[
x(t) = \int_0^t \tikz{\node (ell) [MN] {$\ell$\nodepart{two}$(z)$};
                      \scoped[on background layer]
                      \node [FIT=(ell)];
                      }
                               \, ds
\]
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay] 
\draw[arr] (ell.one south)..controls +(0,-1) and + (0,1).. ++ (-1,-1) node[below] {instant};
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip
    \end{center}
\lipsum[1][3-5]
\end{document}
```

It is somehow similar to @Jasper Habicht answer.

[image]

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but I would prefer not to use \tikzmark and \colorbox, as well as the extra marking you did on the node. Aren't the node labels enough? Is it possible that my code can be extended only a little bit to fix the issue? Just adding the \begin{document} and \end{document} preambles that you mentioned produces a MWE, btw, and sorry for not including that.

Comment: @Jay, why? your code is, sor but frankly said, a big not working mess, so I wrote my answer from scratch. But, all is up to you. I decide to suggest to close your question unclear.

Comment: I apologized for not including a MWE, excuse me. But I wanted to learn *why* my code doesn't work as expected, and not just get a working example using other commands that I'm unfamiliar with. Clearly, the nested tikz commands in my example must have been interacting with the node positioning in a weird way; otherwise, if the "ell" node was correctly labeled, then the arrow would've been in the correct position. Again, thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `remember picture` to the a `tikz` environment in order to be able to refer to a node outside of the current environment. However, you should not nest `tikz` environments. This will break several things, of which the right positioning of coordinates using `remember picture` is only one.

Zarko's answer is in fact better and simpler than the following, but I still would like to post this to show you how you could use the `fit` library (in combination with the `backgrounds` library) to "nest" nodes. More correctly, the nodes are not nested, but a node is drawn that is as large as necessary to wrap the other nodes. This would be the correct way to create what you tried if you really wanted to typeset the blue box using Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\[
x(t) = \int_0^t 
    \tikz[remember picture, baseline]{ 
        \node[anchor=base, inner sep=0pt] (ell) {$\ell$}; 
        \node[anchor=base west, inner sep=0pt] (z) at (ell.base east) {$(z)$}; 
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node[fill=blue!20, fit={(ell) (z)}] {};
        \end{scope}
    } \, ds
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[black, thick, ->, shorten <=2pt] (ell.270) to [in=90, out=245] ++(225:2cm) node[anchor=north] {instant};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]